# What's the difference between array[][] and array[,]?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can someone explain the difference between these two declarations?

1. `double dArray[][];`
2. `double dArray[,];`

Comment: actually as posted this is not valid C#

Comment: because it's `double[][] dArray;` and `double[,] dArray;`

Comment: @user: I'm not @BrokenGlass, but unlike in C and Java, in C# you need to declare the type as `double[][]` and `double[,]` as opposed to placing the brackets on the variable name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double dArray[][];
```

is Array-of-arrays while

```
double dArray[,];
```

is a two dimentional array.

it's easy enough to look them up.

[MSDN Reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The last syntax is easy, it declares a multidimensional array of doubles. Imagine the array is 3x2, then there would be 6 doubles in the array.

The 1st syntax declares a jagged array. The second syntax is rectangular or square, but this syntax need not be. You could have three rows, followed by 3 columns, then 2 columns, then 1 column, ie: its jagged.

```
2nd: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3
     2-1, 2-2, 2-3

1st: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3
     2-1, 2-2,
     3-1,
```

Answer (score 3):

The first is an array of `double` arrays, meaning each separate element in `dArray` can contain a different number of doubles depending on the length of the array.

```
double[][] dArray = new double[3][];
dArray[0] = new double[3];
dArray[1] = new double[2];
dArray[2] = new double[4];

           Index
        0       1       2
      -----   -----   -----
L  1  |   |   |   |   |   |
e     -----   -----   -----
n  2  |   |   |   |   |   |
g     -----   -----   -----
t  3  |   |           |   |
h     -----           -----
   4                  |   |
                      -----
```

The second is called a multidimensional array, and can be thought of as a matrix, like rows and columns.

```
double[,] dArray = new dArray[3, 3];

         Column
        0   1   2
      -------------
   0  |   |   |   |
R     -------------
o  1  |   |   |   |
w     -------------
   2  |   |   |   |
      -------------
```

Answer (score 1):

[See the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (click on the *C#* tab).